# Can I connect a DSL modem to Ethernet broadband connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, dsl, broadband

I have a ethernet port in my house for my broadband connection given by my ISP. I have a Dlink DAP 1350 Pocket Router connected to it. But it only gives me enough range for a room.

I have a old DSL modem router lying in my house. I want to somehow connect this to my broadband internet so that I can use my DAP 1350 as a wireless repeater.

Is this possible?

Comment: Without knowing more, I can't be certain, but rather than do that, could you not use the old DSL modem router as the wireless repeater, placing it where you want.  I've done this in the past, using an old BT DSL Modem/Wireless Router as a wireless repeater.  Note though that this only works with WEP, not WPA/PSK, so you're reducing your security *a lot* doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with your actual devices.

*DAP-1350* is a neutral router, that means it will join two networks, but it doesn't have a modem. It connects directly with an *RJ45* (ethernet cable). A DSL modem usually has a *RJ11* connector and uses the phone line to *dial* a connection. Since the slots are different between the devices and you have an ethernet port in your house, that configuration can't be achieved.

If your actual router gives a decent WiFi range, I would suggest to buy a *WiFi repeater* to be able to extend the WiFi range.